# What's the timeline of a GC implementation in mainstream C++ compilers?

Tags: c++, c++11

As we know, C++11 allows GC, but none of the mainstream compilers supports that.

Is there any discussion when this can be implemented in mainstream compilers like `GCC`, `MSVC`, `Intel Compilers`, `Clang`, etc.

I am looking forward using this feature.

Comment: Can't cite anything on this, but I believe everything GC related ended up removed from the standard.  Edit: Quick google shows that a few things were put into place so that garbage collection would be less hampered, but that it is by no means required or expected (i.e. implementation defined).

Comment: If you are *really really* looking forward to using a GC, then maybe you should be using a different language. Take a look at [D](http://dlang.org/)

Comment: What's stopping you using the GCs already available for C++03? (Not saying there aren't some potentially valid reasons, but asking what your problems have been...)

Comment: Why exactly do you want GC? C++11 has decent solutions for automatically managed dynamic memory.

Comment: Just speculation, but I believe that none of the mainstream C++ compilers will ever implement GC.  It was never intended to be included in the base language, and there's by no means a high demand for it.  (Especially since, as KillianDS mentioned, there are already decent solutions other than GC.)

Comment: @KillianDS: my main worry (and I do consider myself decently experienced) is not generally in memory management per se; it is reading in areas of memory that have been freed. It is *so* easy in C++ to get into such a situation, even when being careful, and we have to go to so much pain in order to avoid it... of course, with a GC you trade invalid reads for space leaks...

Comment: @KillianDS, dynamic memory management can't solve everything, e.g. cyclic references (I know weak_ptr can be used in this case but it would not be pratical in large projects where objects references might be complicated and the cycle may be too large to reason at developing time).  I think the ideal use case of GC is on C++ written servers, that developers make their best efforts eliminating memory leaks but gc takes care of other edge cases so servers won't crash OOM every once a while, improving stability.

Comment: @icando: actually, the problem of cycles is even with a more advanced gc mechanism a problem because of RAII. If you have cycles, it is very hard to decide which destructor you should call first and I'm not even sure if you can handle that correctly in C++ without a construct like `weak_ptr`. As to your first point: Reading invalid memory itself and how it is handled has nothing to do with GC.

Comment: @KillianDS There are (niche) reasons to use GCs even in the presence of C++'s solutions for managing memory. As an example, many lock-free data structures are so much simpler to implement if only you could leak the memory (like, five times less code or better). A GC allows you to do exactly that. The alternative is to implement your own GC-like scheme :S. I agree that in general, a GC is not needed, but sometimes you can be really pinning for one.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I fully agree with that, but that are, like you say, mostly niches. Imho, the (theoretical) best approach would even be to implement a (memory-only) GC for those structures, that ignores RAII, exception safety and the likes and uses a simplified model for this specific use case. In general these c++-specific structures make generic GC very hard to do and usually not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An implementation that incorporates garbage collection probably can't conform to C++98 or C++03. C++11 adds enough to allow conformance, and goes just a baby step beyond that to try to make it marginally reasonable.

There was a proposal to add more comprehensive GC support to the standard, but it was rejected. I think the rejection was quite reasonable. The proposal had around 40 pages of changes to the standard, but in the end all of it was to support one non-normative footnote saying something like: "It is expected that quality implementations will attempt to maximize the memory available to programs."

As far as implementations go, at one time (in the egcs days) there was talk of incorporating (a modified version of) the Boehm-Demers-Weiser collector into egcs. I seem to recall that there was at least one version that did so, to at least some degree (though I don't remember whether it was ever considered a "release" version or not). That, however, was a long time ago, and as far as I know nobody's worked on it in years. Gcc has changed enough in the meantime that if somebody wanted to do it today, they'd probably have to start over from the beginning.

I suppose this gets rid of at least one area in which Microsoft's C++/CLI didn't used to conform with the standard, so depending on how much conformance you want elsewhere, you could (sort of) treat C++/CLI as C++ with garbage collection. Most people think of it in less complimentary terms though (and even Microsoft recommends it only for linking interop between .NET and real C++).

Clang targets LLVM, which includes hooks to support GC (that have been used and proven in other projects). As such, it probably stands the best chance of producing a working implementation some time relatively soon.

Although I could obviously be wrong, I wouldn't expect Intel to incorporate a garbage collector any time soon. Intel concentrates on producing the best output code, and GC probably wouldn't help that a whole lot. The major reason they'd be likely to do so would be to simplify multithreading, another area where Intel puts a lot of effort (but more in libraries than the compiler itself, at least so far).

As for GC coming into mainstream use in most released C++ code, there seems to be little or no demand or even interest. When I originally wrote this answer, I guessed somebody would have written one by now. During that time, interest in GC for C++ seems to have waned, to the point that I'm not at all convinced that it's ever really likely to happen any more. It could still happen, but I don't see enough interest to predict a time frame when it's at all likely. If anything, I'd guess there's probably more interest in moving toward a Rust-like model that explicitly codifies some RAII semantics (but although that general idea appears to be generating some interest, I haven't seen anything specific enough to predict when it's likely to happen either).

Comment: "An implementation that incorporates garbage collection probably can't conform to C++98 or C++03". Indeed it can't implement GC for all objects allocated with `new`, because of the risk that someone might store a pointer to a collected object as the 3DES-encrypted result of casting to `intptr_t`, then later decode and cast back. C++11 has the definition of a "safely-derived pointer". The effect is that code that would break a garbage collector has undefined behavior on an implementation that documents itself as having so-called "strict pointer safety", hence is not portable C++11.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Right -- I only used "probably" to avoid arguments about "a sufficiently intelligent compiler might be able to track the data flow and figure out that what's being stored will eventually be restored to a pointer to X" (which I've run into in the past when I said it simply wasn't possible).

Comment: heh. I used the example of 3DES-encrypting your pointers for exactly the same reason. That'd be some smart compiler. You could have a pessimistic GC, though, where any conversion to `intptr_t` (followed by data escape) converts the GC object that the pointer points into, to a GC root until it's freed. It just would not then GC all objects allocated with `new`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yeah -- I argued then that no matter how smart you make the compiler, somebody can out-smart it. I thought writing it to a USB drive, which was then removed from the system for an arbitrary length of time, but eventually plugged back worked pretty well too. If that's memory mapped, it might not be visible to the program that any transformation to the pointer has taken place at all -- it's just copying the pointer into another location that then disappears for a while.

Comment: Good point about the memory mapping, that beats my suggested GC implementation above unless it also treats writes to mapped memory (and IPC-shared memory) in the same way as conversions to `intptr_t`. That would be very inefficient short of some non-standard hardware support, and there's a problem in general with GC implementations that surprisingly don't collect your memory, as I learned at a past employer when there was a bug in our JVM implementation. People's apps ran out of memory and crashed.

Comment: @SteveJessop: The problem at that point is that the the extra tests for mapped memory potentially slow operation a fair amount, *and* depending on viewpoint, on some systems essentially all memory is "mapped" (from the swap file if not elsewhere).

Answer (score 12):

You misunderstood a bit.

C++11 has support for better integration with GC, thanks to a few key functions to help them better analyze what is reachable and what is not. If you check the new [`<memory>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) header you will notice:

- `declare_reachable`: declares that an object can not be recycled
- `undeclare_reachable`: declares that an object can be recycled
- `declare_no_pointers`: declares that a memory area does not contain traceable pointers
- `undeclare_no_pointers`: cancels the effect of std::declare_no_pointers

This does not mean however that C++11 recommends using a GC or pushes compilers to integrate a GC.

Some GCs, such as [Boehm-Demers-Weiser](https://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/)'s, already exist. This new API is just a standardization of the interface to interact with them both for:

- correctness: `declare_reachable` may help in some situations, though it should be automatic in most cases
- performance: such GC are not type-aware and might mistakenly detect pointers in memory areas that contain integers, for example; `declare_no_pointers` eliminates the need to scan some memory areas, increasing performance and reducing false-positives (which in turn increase performance some more)

So you can *already* use the Boehm's garbage collector if you wish, C++11 merely improves on it with a standard API so that you can more easily switch from one GC to another.

Comment: Your answer explains what I *wanted to* convey in my answer and it does so better than my answer,deleting mine and upvoting yours :)

Comment: @MatthieuM, I would think integration into compiler can potentially generate better GC code than a library, in terms of performance, correctness, etc.  Compilers can do static analysis, can insert code at needed places to record some information.  It can even generate data structures that help GC track references between objects.  So merely a library implementation is less useful.

Comment: @icando: Yes, but that is not what C++11 is about. C++11 is about supporting libraries, not integrating GC code into compilers. As a consequence, no compiler implementors that I know of expressed any intention of implementing GC runtimes and integrated support.

Answer (score 3):

The C++11 standard added language support for implementing garbage collection, but no actual working garbage collector. The most prominent example of a working gc library for C++ is [Hans Boehm's implementation](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/). To my knowledge, there are no plans to integrate this library with any of the major compilers at the moment, but it has been hinted several times that the standard's committee is very much interested(*) in integrating a garbage collector with the next version of C++.

(*) See, for example, the [expert panel at Going Native 2012](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Interactive-Panel-The-Importance-of-Being-Native)

Comment: More accurately, a couple of specific members are interested. Bjarne has said implied that the current situation (optional GC) is what he wants. Herb seems to want mandatory GC -- but he seems to be nearly the only one who's strongly in favor of it. Most others I've talked to don't care much, and a few are opposed to some degree.