# Are there practical uses of C++11's Garbage Collection ABI?

Tags: c++, c++11, garbage-collection

C++11 introduced an [interface to garbage collectors](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#gc-abi). From what I see, it provides a standardized way to communicate with the GC (e.g. [declare_no_pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee410585.aspx)), and to get information about how disguised pointers are handled (e.g., [get_pointer_safety](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee410608.aspx)).

However, there is no standardized way in C++11 yet to allocate a raw block of memory, which you don't have to free manually. There are use cases where that would help, even if destructors are not called. One example is to implement efficient concurrent data structures (as mentioned by Herb Sutter) without having to deal with complicated cleanup protocols.

So far, so good. My question (from the perspective of an ordinary develper, not a GC library developer):

**Is there a real-world example where the new C++11 GC interface has helped you?**

At least from my perspective the world has not changed. If you need GC, you still have to find a non-standard library, for example [Boehm GC](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/), and learn how to integrate and use it. The new standardized interface won't help very much in that respect. It will also not solve portability issues.

(In the long term, the common interface defined by the C++11 standard hopefully pays off. However, my question targets only the immediate future.)

Comment: This isn't supported by any compiler AFAIK.

Comment: @Rapptz: Clang and gcc don't support it, but msvc does.

Comment: I'm probably going to get flamed by a minuscule but loud minority, but who the hell would want GC in C++? We already have RAII, and this beats GC anytime, as far as C++ semantics are concerned. But, admittedly, it may be useful in other languages that don't have the same expectations -- eg. I'm a big Lisp fan and I can't imagine it without GC.

Comment: @syam Let me support you. Garbage collection is the single greatest enemy of fast programs (apart from badly-chosen algorithms).

Comment: @H2CO3 Funnily enough, my comment didn't yield the uproar I was fearing. I guess I was wrong thinking it was controversial. (good thing too, I love being wrong in such cases) :)

Comment: @syam Controversial? You're talking about C++. Who ever wants GC there probably just doesn't know the language well enough to dare post a reply to your comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no *currently* practical usage of C++11 GC interface as there is no compiler which fully supports this API in the meantime. Also, C++11 standard declares this API as optional and there is no  movement seen to implement it in the major compilers (but as Jesse Good notes MSVC already does support it).

Also you should look this post, it has related information: [Why garbage collection when RAII is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17261912/2149111)

Comment: Thank you for the link. Here is another related answer that I found useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578627/whats-the-timeline-of-a-gc-implementation-in-mainstream-c-compilers/10578761#10578761

Answer (score 2):

`std::shared_ptr` provides what is called reference-counted garbage collection.  It is simple to implement but has some drawbacks.  Specifically it is less efficient than alternative forms of garbage collection in many applications, and more importantly it cannot handle cyclic references.

Java and C# are called "managed languages" as opposed to C++ which is called an "unmanaged language" mostly because they implement mark-and-sweep garbage collection.  Mark-and-sweep garbage collection handles cyclic references.  It does this by logically searching the graph of reachable objects, then periodically deleting those that are unreachable.  There are more sophisticated algorithms that are optimizations of this (one is called "generational"), but the underlying structure is just mark-and-sweep.

The problem with implementing mark-and-sweep in C++ is that there are a lot of operations that make it difficult to track the object graph.  The "safely-derived pointer" concept seeks to separate out and define these issues so that we can say which features you can use to maintain the integrity of the GCs view of the object graph.  It should then be possible for a compiler to statically identify and diagnose constructs that violate these (reinterpret casts, pointer arithmetic, and so on).

Those that claim "why would you want garbage collection when you have RAII" are confused.  RAII is one possible memory model which uses an ownership concept.  Each object must be owned by exactly one other object, and that owner is in charge of its lifetime.  For many object models this simply is not natural or conveniant, as one object is referenced by several others, and there is no clear owner.  For many applications you want an objects lifetime to end automatically once it becomes unreferenced, and this is how Java and C# work "by default".

It is my impression that the new memory model and "safely-derived object" concept should lead to a real optional mark-and-sweep garbage collector to be made available in the standard library.  Such a feature would be extremely welcome - but I don't think it is there yet.  The "safely-derived object" stuff is a foundation for things to come.

Comment: *"Java and C++ are called "Managed languages, as opposed to C++ wich is called "unmanaged language""* Thats only terminology created by Microsoft to differentiate between .NET languages and native languages: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_code

Comment: @Manu343726: Maybe originally, but the terminology is in common use now.  My point is that automatic mark-and-sweep garbage collection is the main differentiator between Java/C# and C++.

Comment: @user1131467 Just nitpicking, but M&S is phasing out nowadays... Generational GC is getting more prevalent, and good ol' reference counting (+ cycle elimination) is gaining a lot of traction the bigger the managed memory area gets (in order to improve locality).

Comment: @syam: Generational GC is an optimized form of mark-and-sweep.  Generational just means that you assume objects have been reachable for a long-time remain reachable most of the time.  The logical effect and required object graph information is the same as mark-and-sweep.   Reference-counting is not compatible with cycle elimination, so I am not sure what you mean (can you provide a citation for this "gaining of traction"?).  The most common of the rare situations where reference-counting is preferable is in real-time applications where randomly stopping for GC is unacceptable.

Comment: @syam: If you're interested in this stuff you should watch lecture ["17-01 through 17-05"](https://class.coursera.org/compilers/lecture/index) of the Stanford Compilers course, it provides an accessible overview of the different garbage collection algorithms and the issues involved.

Comment: @user1131467 Refcounting is definitely compatible with cycle elimination, even in parallel non-stopping GCs -- see Bacon et al. Concerning the "gaining traction" part, this may not be used in mainstream implementations yet but with RAM size increasing there is little choice: with M&S you have too much cache trashing, there are very few other solutions to keep locality at a minimum. (funnily enough, Python uses refcounting + cycle elimination but it has little merit due to its Big Interpreter Lock). Expect to see more Refcount GCs soon...

Comment: As to GenGC, my bad, I was thinking of a specific moving implementation that has little in common with M&S -- you're right most GenGC uses M&S inside generations. -- Also thanks for the link, I'm sure it's interesting but I'm no native english speaker and videos are a no-no for me, I need written material. Anyway I've been looking into GC implementations for quite a few years now, I didn't dig very far but at least I know the basic algorithms and implementations. :)

Comment: [Bacon's Concurrent Cycle Collection in Reference Counted Systems](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=fr&q=Bacon+Concurrent+Cycle+Collection+in+Reference+Counted+Systems) may interest you. Old but good. :)

Comment: @syam: Ok, I just read some of the [Bacon paper here](http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-bacon/Bacon03Pure.pdf).  The cycle elimination part is interesting, and requires some more thought - but it still requires access to the object graph, which it must walk when it finds candidate cycles, and so cannot be implemented as part of `std::shared_ptr` in C++.  The important thing to understand is that to implement GC with cycle elimnation in C++ we first need a reliable run-time view of the object graph - no matter which GC algorithm is used.

Comment: @syam: I will add that it is surprising to me that if an "advanced" reference-counting GC (not to be confused with naive `std::shared_ptr`) is superior to generational GC, then why do the Java VM and .NET runtime use a generational algorithm.  Perhaps these are new results, or perhaps the Java/C# architects are not convinced for some reason.

Comment: Indeed there's also the paper you linked to. And I fully agree, knowledge of the object graph is necessary -- don't get me wrong though, my point only was that refcounting improves locality and thus is more fit to the huge amounts of RAM we have nowadays. As to Java (I don't know about C#) there is this experimental VM (Jikes I think, if memory serves me well) that implements, amongst other schemes, pure refcounting. I'm guessing the official implementations are just taking things slow: why risk changing the scheme when the current one still kinda works? Just a wild guess. :)

Comment: What I mean is, we're not quite yet at several TB of RAM in mainstream systems, so M&S is still viable. But the more RAM space ramps up, the less M&S becomes viable and the more locality we need.

Comment: I probably sound like a nitpicker now, but `shared_ptr` is not garbage collection. if you have circular dependencies it still leaks.

Comment: @Alex, you should use `shared_ptr` paired with `std::weak_ptr` to solve circular references.

Comment: @Alex: As stated in my post reference counting is considered a form of garbage collection, even in the simple form that does not collect cycles.

Answer (score 1):

No. As proved by the final removal of it from C++23 following [P2186](https://wg21.link/p2186). Even though GC has been somewhat successfully applied in C++, it does not benefit from the model specified in the standard. Quote from the paper, with emphasis mine:

> ... Garbage Collection as specified by the Standard **is not useful** for those applications. In fact, the authors **are not aware of any implementations of the strict pointer safety facility**. Unsurprisingly, the authors **are not aware of any uses** either. Indeed, ISOCpp code search only finds hits in GCC and LLVM. Similarly, CppReference tells us that implementations **all offer no support** for this feature. Finally, the specification **falls short in many ways** as outlined above.
>
> ...
>
> **This status-quo hasn’t changed in 12 years.** The maintenance burden on the Standard is near minimal, and we hope the Committee spends almost no time agreeing to remove this unused and unimplemented feature, despite its origins being well-intended and the target use-case still being relevant. Indeed, the current specification simply **missed the mark**, and will not be missed.
>
> We therefore propose outright removal instead of deprecation because lack of implementation and usage makes deprecation moot.

The ways that the author considers the model to fall short include

- Limited ways to obtain safely-derived pointers and poor interplay with placement `new` and allocators
- Underspecification of pointer safety with regards to replacement `new` functions
- Missing `constexpr` in these pointer functions
- Inconsistency between wordings in core language and library
- Inconsistency between "special types" (`char`,`signed char`,`unsigned char` and `char8_t` for "traceable pointer objects", while one would expect `char`, `unsigned char` and `std::byte` instead)
- Only "relaxed" is in practical use among the possible values for `std::get_pointer_safety`

...and others.